# Login screen shows "Guest" option even though it is disabled

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, login, login-screen, guest-account

I have disabled the "Guest" option on my Macbook Pro, however it still shows the "Guest" bubble next to my account on the login screen.

Comment: What OS X version?

Comment: Have you modified the `Directory Utility` configurations at all?

Comment: @slick OS X El Capitan 10.11.3

Comment: @njboot Haven't touched it

Comment: Is Find my Mac switched on? That sets the Guest account up as a honey-trap.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's been turned off

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to remove the Guest account is to disable Find My Mac in iCloud settings.

Check this out: [Disable guest account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209049/disable-the-guest-user-completely-in-el-capitan-without-having-to-disable-find)

Comment: I have already done that and "Guest" is still there on logon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. I solve it by reenable and disable it again, but in the last step I also change the option in **Login Option** on **Display login windows as:** from **List of users** to **Name and password**. I guess the trigger is enable and disable it again. It might be a problem from the El Capitan. I hope this help.

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work.